# Maze least turns

Tags: c++, algorithm, maze

I  have a problem that i can't solve.I have a maze and I have to find a path from a point S to a point E,which has the least turns.It is known that the point E is reacheable.I can move only in 4 directions,left,right,up and down.It doesn't have to be the shortest path,just to have least turns.

I tried to store the number of turns  in a priority queue.For example when I reach a certain place in the maze I will add the numbers of turns till there.From there I would add his neighbours to the priority queue,if they weren't visited already or they weren't walls,with the value of the current block i was sitting,for example t + x which can have the following values ( 0-if the neighbour is facing in the same direction I was facing when i got near him,or 1 if it is in a different direction).It seems that this approach doesn't work for every case.

I will appreciate if somebody could offer me some hints, without any code.

Comment: Enumerate all paths, take the one with the least turns. To optimize remember the shortest solution to date and abort exploration of a partial solution once it cannot result in a shorter path anymore.

Comment: Do you understand the idea of a breadth-first search?

Comment: Change the list of neighbors of a given intersection **A** in the maze to include every intersection reachable from **A** in a straight line. ("Intersections" includes the start and end of the maze.) Now find the shortest path.

Comment: @beaker's way is very nice -- it lets you find the optimal answer with a simple BFS instead of needing the more complicated Dijkstra's or A* algorithms.  (A good heuristic for A* could make it faster than BFS, but it seems hard to come up with one that cares only about turns, and not about distance.)  Remember to ignore (position, direction) state ***pairs*** that you have already visited (as usual).  For efficiency, generate *only* the children that involve a turn as the first move (since moves in the same direction have already been generated as siblings).

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track. What you need to implement for this problem is [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm). You just need to consider not just points as graph vertices, but pair of `(point,direction)`. From every vertex `(p,d)` you have 5 edges (although last one can be blocked by wall): `(p,0)`, `(p,1)`, `(p,2)`, `(p,3)`, `(neighbour of p in direction d, d)`. First four edges are of weight 1 (as you turn here), and the last one is of weight 0 (no turn, just move forward). Algorithm is good enough to ignore loops and works fine for edges of weight 0. You should end when any vertex `(end point, _)` is extracted from priority queue.

This method has one issue, as too many verticies are inspected in the process. If your maze is small, that's not the problem. Otherwise, consider a slight modification known as [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). You need a good heuristic function, describing lower bound on number of turns to the goal.

Comment: This is basically right, but I'm confused by the 5 edges.  Since the moves are just U, D, L and R, I think there are at most 4 graph vertices per location, each corresponding to the incoming direction, and each of which could be blocked by a wall.  (You may want the start location to have a special "don't care" direction -- in that case there would be just one vertex corresponding to that location.)